# how to get value from boundfield then pass it to item template field?

Tags: gridview

here I have a trouble to get value from bound field to template field..

```
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />


            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="productid" DataField="productid" 
                SortExpression="productid" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="categoryid" DataField="categoryid" 
                SortExpression="categoryid" />

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="productname" DataField="productname" 
                SortExpression="productname" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="unitsinstock" DataField="unitsinstock" 
                SortExpression="unitsinstock" />

        <asp:TemplateField>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

Here is my Code:

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

```
    TextBox text_ref = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox2");


}
```

Here when user click edit link in gridview, the boundfield value should transfer to textbox control inside of the item template.

but above code not working. how to achieve this?
how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug your code and inspect the runtime values. Your code seems right, but make sure that the cell index (3 in your code) is the cell where the template control belongs: for me that's the suspicious part.

Comment: yeah, but when I place 'TextBox2' Outside of the Gridview I am getting that cell index 3 value. but its not coming inside of the gridview. I don't know how to solve..?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the RowEditing event, then inspect (debug window) the GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[3].Controls object: it should return a collection of controls assigned to the cell. I think that the Controls[1] item should be the TextBox control, but check it in VS. Unfortunately I'm in a Linux machine right now and can't test this.

Comment: when debugging, I m geeting value like this.  e.NewEditIndex=0   and    text_ref=Null

Comment: Then I think your code is firing the new row event! Instead of the edit event... You should check into that.

Comment: I got output without doing c# code.just added editemplate instead of itemtemplate then added on lable inside the edittemplate then,binded unitprice value.now its working.